# Сбивчивое/сбившееся/сбивающееся дыхание. Как можно, а как нельзя?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, выбор-слов

Вся суть вопроса в заголовке. Можно ли сказать "сбившееся дыхание" или "сбивающееся дыхание"? Если можно, то в каких случаях какое выражение лучше употребить?

Answer (score 3):

***Сбившееся*** - то, которое сбилось. Причастие совершенного вида прошедшего времени, указывает на временный признак по действию.

***Сбивающееся*** - то, которое сбивается. Причастие несовершенного вида настоящего времени, указывает на временный признак по действию.

***Сбивчивое*** - син. **неровное**, прилагательное, указывает на постоянный признак, не развивающийся во времени.

Все три варианта корректны и могут быть определениями при слове "дыхание".

Answer (score 3):

Три варианта возможны, но чем они отличаются?

1) **Прилагательное** обозначает постоянный во времени признак:

Не давай опомниться, ты уже идешь, говори на ходу, пусть услышит **сбивчивое** дыхание… ―  [Александр Терехов. Каменный мост (1997-2008)]

2) **Причастие прошедшего времени** обозначает признак, отнесенный к промежутку времени, когда дыхание сбилось.

Помолчал и Коль, стараясь выровнять **сразу сбившееся** дыхание. [Вячеслав Рыбаков. Вода и кораблики (1992)].  **Нехорошо** **сбившееся** дыхание снова упорядочилось.  [Ю. М. Нагибин. Смерть на вокзале (1972-1979)]

3) **Причастие настоящего времени**  обозначает признак, который меняется во времени (то сбивается, то восстанавливается):

Я слышу его **сбивающееся дыхание**, его пальцы, которые то гладят, то терзают мою несчастную, обезумевшую руку. [Галина Щербакова. Loveстория (1996)]